# Initial scaling in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a problem using the shiny package in R. I'm trying to insert income. debt and bonus entered in the slider that I've built into the original data set so the algorithm can scale i.e. normalise the data to make the calculation. Right now I can only make the calculation as-is i.e. when you enter the data it calculates it however, as I indicated, I want the data entered to go back into the original data set so I can scale it before making the calculation. I have the below code for the shiny package.

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
          headerPanel("Calculating fwbs"),
          sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("Income", "Please Select Income: ", min=0, max=5000, 
                        value=2500, step=100),
            sliderInput("Debt", "Please Select Debt: ", min = 0, max=2500, 
                        value=1250, step = 100),
            sliderInput("Bonus", "Have you received any bonus: ", min=0, max= 1000, 
                        value=500, step =100)
          ),
          mainPanel(
            textOutput("fwbi")
          )
        ))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$fwbi <- renderText({
    income2<- input$Income
    debt2<- input$Debt
    bonus2<- input$Bonus
    paste("Your fwbi is: ", income2 + debt2 + bonus2)
  })
})
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a small reproducible dataset and the expected output as it is not clear about how the scaling should be done

Comment: the original data set has 3 columns income, debt and bonus with 10000 random variables generated for each. the data that I've entered should be included in that list so I can normalise the data that I entered

Comment: Is my interpretation correct that you wish to add the user entered data as another row in the original data frame?

Comment: Kind of. I want to put the data into original data so I can normalise it. and calculate the fwbi. Upon normalisation the data will probably be between [-1,1] then I'll calculate the fwbi using the normalised version

Comment: I don't need to see the table at all. I'm only using the data to normalise the entry to calculate the fwbi that's it @Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to add an arbitrary number of rows to the original data, you can use a `reactiveValues` list:

```
Dframe <- data.frame(income = rnorm(5),
                     debt = rnorm(5),
                     bonus = rnorm(5))

library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        headerPanel("Calculating fwbs"),
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("Income", "Please Select Income: ", min=0, max=5000, 
                      value=2500, step=100),
          sliderInput("Debt", "Please Select Debt: ", min = 0, max=2500, 
                      value=1250, step = 100),
          sliderInput("Bonus", "Have you received any bonus: ", min=0, max= 1000, 
                      value=500, step =100),
          actionButton(inputId = "btn_add_to_data",
                       label = "Add To Data")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          textOutput("fwbi"),
          tableOutput("data")
        )
      )
    ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

      # Store the original data at start up.
      Data <- reactiveValues(
        Source = Dframe
      )

      # Every time you click "Add Data", it will add the user-input to Data$Source
      observeEvent(
        input$btn_add_to_data,
        {
          new_row <- data.frame(income = input$Income,
                                debt = input$Debt,
                                bonus = input$Bonus)

          Data$Source <- rbind(Data$Source,
                               new_row)
        }
      )

      output$fwbi <- renderText({
        income2<- input$Income
        debt2<- input$Debt
        bonus2<- input$Bonus
        paste("Your fwbi is: ", 
              scale(Data$Source$income) + 
              scale(Data$Source$debt) + 
              scale(Data$Source$bonus))
      })

      output$data <- renderTable({
        Data$Source
      })
    })
)
```

If you want to limit the user to only adding one row, you can use an `eventReactive`

```
Dframe <- data.frame(income = rnorm(5),
                     debt = rnorm(5),
                     bonus = rnorm(5))

library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        headerPanel("Calculating fwbs"),
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("Income", "Please Select Income: ", min=0, max=5000, 
                      value=2500, step=100),
          sliderInput("Debt", "Please Select Debt: ", min = 0, max=2500, 
                      value=1250, step = 100),
          sliderInput("Bonus", "Have you received any bonus: ", min=0, max= 1000, 
                      value=500, step =100),
          actionButton(inputId = "btn_add_to_data",
                       label = "Add To Data")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          textOutput("fwbi"),
          tableOutput("data")
        )
      )
    ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

      NewData <- eventReactive(
        input$btn_add_to_data,
        {
          new_row <- data.frame(income = input$Income,
                                debt = input$Debt,
                                bonus = input$Bonus)

          rbind(Dframe,
                new_row)
        }
      )

      output$fwbi <- renderText({
        income2<- input$Income
        debt2<- input$Debt
        bonus2<- input$Bonus
        paste("Your fwbi is: ", 
              scale(NewData()$income) + 
              scale(NewData()$debt) + 
              scale(NewData()$bonus))
      })

      output$data <- renderTable({
        NewData()
      })
    })
)
```

Comment: sorry maybe I'm not clear enough. I want to add data chosen by the sliders to the original data set so I can scale it using the original data set. i.e. let's say that my original data set consists of only a single column (income) and the values are 1000, 2000, 1250, 1400. I chose 1300 in the slider. What I want to do is add the 1350 value to the original data set so it can scale it with the whole data set. Let's say it scaled 1350 to 0.20 and then call the 0.20 to make the calculation @Benjamin

Comment: I haven't scaled the data as it seemed from your question that you had already decided on how to do the scaling once you had the appropriate data structure.  It was my understanding that the crux of the question was how to add the three input values as a new row in the original data frame.  In both my cases, `Dframe` starts with 5 rows, and after clicking the button, the result has 6 (or more) rows against which you may normalize.  Is there a different interpretation of "add to the data" that I'm not understanding (that sounds more snarky than I mean it).

Comment: how do I return the normalised data into my calculation then i.e. return it to fbwi = income2 + bonus2 + debt2

Comment: I added some edits in the `output$fwbi`.  Not knowing what algorithm you intend to use for scaling, I just used the `scale` function.  Whatever the algorithm is, we can refer to the reactive objects to perform our calculations.

Comment: @Benjamin I think the OP is kind of asking others to check what is in his/her mind

Comment: @Benjamin your above code worked. thank you. However, one problem that I have is it opens and closes automatically

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior you're seeing. the application runs stably for me

Answer (score 0):

We can change the codes to

```
library(shiny)
library(DT
```

-create a function

```
fscale <- function(data  = NULL) {
  
  

ui <- fluidPage(
          
          headerPanel(title = "Calculating fwbs"),
          
          sidebarPanel(
            
            sliderInput("Income", "Please Select Income: ", min=0, max=5000, 
                        value=2500, step=100),
            sliderInput("Debt", "Please Select Debt: ", min = 0, max=2500, 
                        value=1250, step = 100),
            sliderInput("Bonus", "Have you received any bonus: ", min=0, max= 1000, 
                        value=500, step =100),
            numericInput("n", "Number of rows to scale:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
            
            
          ),
          
          mainPanel(
            
              textOutput("fwbi"),
              dataTableOutput("data"))
          )
       
        

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  dat_scale <- reactive({
    
    n1 <- seq_len(input$n)
    data[["Income"]][n1] <-  (data$Income[n1] - input$Income)/data$Income[n1]
    data[["Debt"]][n1] <- (data$Debt[n1] - input$Debt)/data$Debt[n1]
    data[["Bonus"]][n1] <- (data$Bonus[n1] - input$Bonus)/data$Bonus[n1]
    data
  })  
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    dat_scale()
    
  })
  
  output$fwbi <- renderText({
    income2<- input$Income
    debt2<- input$Debt
    bonus2<- input$Bonus
    paste("Your fwbi is: ", income2 + debt2 + bonus2)
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)

}
```

-run the function

```
fscale(df1)
```

-output
[image]

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Income  = sample(0:5000, 25, replace = TRUE),
              Debt = sample(0:2500, 25, replace = TRUE),
               Bonus = sample(0:1000, 25, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: again this doesn't return the normalise calculation it adds up income, debt and bonus as it is. it doesn't normalise income, debt and bonus

Comment: @Yags That is the reason I asked what is the expected output.  If you just post something and your expected output is in your mind, we cannot help.  In your code, it is adding up those.  How do others know what kind of normalization you need. If you check the data output, it is normalizing based on an algorithm, which you can change if you want to.  Anyway, no more comments to you

Comment: the expected output shouldn't be more than 5 for the fwbi

Comment: @Yags Where is it written in your post.  If it is in your mind, I can't help

Comment: @Yags Anyway, added the number of rows to scale